# Deserialization fails

Tags: asp.net

this is my code

```
            DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(" Prueba1"));
            DropDownList2.Items.Add(new ListItem(" Prueba1"));

//string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\hmfsw\web\DTCWIN107\MYSITE.com\public_html\post\");

// Make a reference to a directory.
            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\hmfsw\web\DTCWIN107\MYSITE.com\public_html\post\");
            string path = @"\\hmfsw\web\DTCWIN107\MYSITE.com\public_html\linker\linker.xml";

// Get a reference to each file in that directory.
            FileInfo[] fiArr = di.GetFiles();

 // Display the names of the files.
            foreach (FileInfo fri in fiArr)DropDownList1.Items.Add(new ListItem(fri.Name));


            System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer =
            new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(selector));
            System.IO.TextReader reader =
            new System.IO.StreamReader(path);
            selector s = (selector)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
```

OKay,  The first thing is that the dropdownlist daes not update with prueba1 and prueba2

But the dropdownlist do update with info of the folder...

And the second thiing is that the serializer.Deserialize daes nothing. The dropdownlist is not been load with the xml ...

Could you plz  help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any association between Dropdownlist and the selector.